# How do I separate two values in one column in a CSV file?

Tags: csv

I have a CSV file with a column that has two names in it. How do I separate those two values so that the one column becomes two columns, each with a name in it?

Comment: Could you provide at least one sample line, please?

Comment: The name of the column is "Actors" and in the field, it will say "Mel Gibson, Danny Glover"